# Motion Event Action Move is not working in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-custom-view

I have a problem with my android emulator, I have a custom view and for controlling the touch event I use onTochEvent in my class. so for different kind of events (ex:‌down, up, move ...), I have righted a case. for down and up the emulator shows no problem but with the move, there is no action. on my phone, everything is just fine! i have tried different kinds of API too but didn't work. this is my onTouch code :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xd = event.getX();
            yd = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float xm = event.getX();
            float ym = event.getY();
            if(card.left < xm && card.right > xm){
                if(card.top < ym && card.bottom > ym){
                    card.top += yd - ym;
                    card.left += xd - xm;
                    card.right += xd - xm;
                    card.bottom += yd - ym;
                    postInvalidate();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            break;
        default:
    }
    return result;
}
```

android studio 3.3 api 24. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view needs to `return true` on first ACTION_DOWN event, only then it will receive successive touch events.

return `super.onTouchEvent(event);` only when you don't want to handle any particular kind of touch event.